# How to spec a Python mock which defaults to AttributeError() without explicit assignment?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a question related to Python `unittest.mock.Mock` and `spec_set` functionalities.

My goal is to create a Mock with the following functionalities:

1. It has a spec of an arbitrary class I decide at creation time.
2. I must be able to assign on the mock only attributes or methods according to the spec of point 1
3. The Mock must raise AttributeError in the following situations:

   - I try to assign an attribute that is not in the spec
   - I call or retrieve a property that is either missing in the `spec_set`, or present in the `spec_set` but assigned according to the above point.

Some examples of the behavior I would like:

```
class MyClass:
   property: int = 5
   def func() -> int:
       pass

# MySpecialMock is the Mock with the functionalities I am dreaming about :D
mock = MyMySpecialMock(spec_set=MyClass)

mock.not_existing # Raise AttributeError
mock.func() # Raise AttributeError
mock.func = lambda: "it works"
mock.func() # Returns "it works"
```

I have tried multiple solutions without any luck, or without being explicitly verbose. The following are some examples:

1. Using `Mock(spec_set=...)`, but it does not raise errors in case I call a specced attribute which I did not explicitly set
2. Using `Mock(spec_set=...)` and explicitly override every attribute with a function with an Exception side effect, but it is quite verbose since I must repeat all the attributes...

My goal is to find a way to automatize 2, but I have no clean way to do so. Did you ever encounter such a problem, and solve it?

For the curious ones, the goal is being able to enhance the separation of unit testings; I want to be sure that my mocks are called only on the methods I explicitly set, to avoid weird and unexpected side effects.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a satisfying answer to my problem, by using the `dir` method.

To create the Mock with the requirements I listed above, it should be enough to do the following:

```
def create_mock(spec: Any) -> Mock:
    mock = Mock(spec_set=spec)

    attributes_to_override = dir(spec)
    for attr in filter(lambda name: not name.startswith("__"), attributes_to_override):
        setattr(mock, attr, Mock(side_effect=AttributeError(f"{attr} not implemented")))

    return mock
```

Answer (score 0):

`spec_set` defines a `mock` object which is the same as the class, but then doesn't allow any changes to be made to it, since it defines special `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. This means that the first test (calling a non-existent attr) will fail as expected, but then so will trying to set an attr:

```
from unitest import mock

class X:
    pass

m = mock.Mock(spec_set=X)
m.func()
# __getattr__: AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'func'
m.func = lambda: "it works"
# __setattr__: AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'func'
```

Instead, you can use `create_autospec()` which copies an existing function, and adds the `mock` functions to it, but without affecting `__setattr__`:

```
n = mock.create_autospec(X)
n.func()
# __getattr__: AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'func'
n.func = lambda: "it works"
n.func()
# 'it works'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I am afraid this would create a slightly different behaviour than what I described; my goal would be to have that class `X` like:
```
class X:
   def func():
        pass
```

with the following behavior: 
```
mock_x.func() 
# __getattr__: AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'func'
n.func = lambda: "it works"
n.func()
# 'it works'
```

What I mean is that `func` should indeed be a property of the Spec, but `getattr` must work only after `setattr` has been called.